# I am unable to figure out why my c++ code for huffman tree is working when I am not assigning the values in the heapify function to the variables

Tags: c++, huffman-code, min-heap

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std; 
  
float AverageCodeLength = 0;

// structure of a node containing the input symbol and its corresponding probability
struct Node { 
    char symbol; 
  
    float probability; 
  
    struct Node *left, *right; 
}; 

// structure of a minheap
struct MinHeap { 
  
    int size; 
   
    struct Node** array; 
}; 

// function to create a newnode  
struct Node* createNode(char symbol, float probability) { 
    struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 
  
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL; 
    temp->symbol = symbol; 
    temp->probability = probability; 
  
    return temp; 
} 
  
// function to check whether the provided input is valid or
bool performSanityCheck(char symbols[] ,float probabilities[] , int n){
    
    //check if the total probabilities sum to 1
    float sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
        sum += probabilities[i];
    }

    // cout << sum << "\n";

    if (sum != 1) return true ;

    //check if there are unique symbols being used

    //first we will sort the symbols array

    sort(symbols , symbols + n);

    // printCharacterArray(symbols , n);

    bool flg = false ;

    for (int i = 0 ; i<n-1 ; i++){

        if (symbols[i] == symbols[i+1]){

            flg = true;
            break;

        }
    }

    return flg;
}

// function to swap two nodes
void swapNodes(struct Node** a, struct Node** b) { 
    struct Node* t = *a; 
    *a = *b; 
    *b = t; 
} 
  
// The standard Heapify function. 
void Heapify(struct MinHeap* minHeap, int idx) { 
    int smallest = idx; 
    int left = 2 * idx + 1; 
    int right = 2 * idx + 2; 
    int size = minHeap-> size;
    float lprob = 0 ;
    float rprob = 0 ;
    float sprob = 0;

    if (minHeap->array[left]){
        lprob = minHeap->array[left]->probability;
    } 
    if (minHeap->array[right]){
        rprob = minHeap->array[right]->probability;
    } 
    if (minHeap->array[smallest]){
        lprob = minHeap->array[smallest]->probability;
    } 
    cout << minHeap->array[left]-> probability << " " << minHeap->array[right]-> probability << " " << minHeap->array[smallest]->probability <<  endl;
    
    if (left < size && minHeap->array[left]-> probability < minHeap->array[smallest]->probability) 
        smallest = left; 
  
    if (right < size && minHeap->array[right]-> probability < minHeap->array[smallest]->probability) 
        smallest = right; 
  
    if (smallest != idx) { 
        swapNodes(&minHeap->array[smallest], &minHeap->array[idx]); 
        Heapify(minHeap, smallest); 
    } 
} 
  

//function to extract minimum value from a heap
struct Node* extractMinValue(struct MinHeap* minHeap) { 
  
    struct Node* temp = minHeap->array[0]; 
    minHeap->array[0] = minHeap->array[minHeap->size - 1]; 
  
    minHeap->size -= 1; 
    Heapify(minHeap, 0); 
  
    return temp; 
} 
  
// function to insert a new node in the minHeap
void insertMinHeap(struct MinHeap* minHeap, struct Node* Node) { 
  
    minHeap->size += 1; 
    int i = minHeap->size - 1; 
    float nprob = Node->probability;
    while (i && nprob < minHeap->array[(i - 1) / 2]->probability) { 
  
        minHeap->array[i] = minHeap->array[(i - 1) / 2]; 
        i = (i - 1) / 2; 
    } 
  
    minHeap->array[i] = Node; 
} 
  
// function to build min heap of the given size
struct MinHeap* buildMinHeap(char symbol[], float probability[], int size)   { 
    
    struct MinHeap* minHeap = (struct MinHeap*)malloc(sizeof(struct MinHeap)); 
  
    minHeap->size = size; 
  
    minHeap->array = (struct Node**)malloc(size * sizeof(struct Node*)); 
  
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        minHeap->array[i] = createNode(symbol[i], probability[i]); 
    }

    minHeap->size = size; 

    int n = size - 1;  
  
    for (int i = (n - 1) / 2; i >= 0; --i) 
        Heapify(minHeap, i); 
    
    return minHeap;
} 
  
// function to print an array of integers
void printArr(int arr[], int n) { 
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
        cout<< arr[i]; 
  
    cout<<"\n"; 
} 

//function to print an array of decimal values , i.e , probabilities

void printFloatArray(float arr[] , int n){
    for (int i = 0; i<n ; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

//function to print an array of character , i.e , symbols

void printCharacterArray(char arr[] , int n){
    for (int i = 0; i<n ; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

// function to check if a node is leafnode or not 

bool isLeaf(struct Node* root) { 
    return !(root->left) && !(root->right); 
} 

// function to build huffmantree with the given symbols and their corresponding probabilities 

struct Node* buildHuffmanTree(char symbol[], float probability[], int size) { 
    struct Node *left, *right, *top; 
    struct MinHeap* minHeap = buildMinHeap(symbol, probability, size); 
  
    while (!(minHeap->size == 1)) { 
  
        // here we extract wo minimum values from our heap 
        left = extractMinValue(minHeap); 
        right = extractMinValue(minHeap); 

        // here $ represents a new node which is not an input symbol and represents an internal node while building our huffman tree
        top = createNode('$', left->probability + right->probability); 
  
        top->left = left; 
        top->right = right; 

        // we insert the newly created intermediate node into the minheap
        insertMinHeap(minHeap, top); 
    } 
    // after the tree is being built the minimum value is present at the root of the tree which is being returned here
    return extractMinValue(minHeap); 
} 
  

// function for printing the huffman codes for corresponding symbols

void printHuffManCodes(struct Node* root, int arr[], int top) { 
  
    if (root->left) {  
        arr[top] = 1;
        printHuffManCodes(root->left, arr, top + 1); 
    } 
  
    if (root->right) { 
        arr[top] = 0;
        printHuffManCodes(root->right, arr, top + 1); 
    } 
  
    if (isLeaf(root)) { 
        cout<< " " << root->symbol <<": "; 
        //cout << top << endl;
        //cout << root->probability << endl;
        ::AverageCodeLength += top*root->probability;
        printArr(arr, top); 
    } 
} 
  


int main() { 
  
    // taking user input

    int n ;                 // variable for getting the number of unique symbols 

    char symbols[n];
    float  probabilities[n] ;     //arrays for the symbols and their probablities

    while (true) {

        cout << " Enter the no. of unique symbols ";
        cin >> n ; 

        cout << " Enter the symbols and their corresponding probabilities \n";

        for (int i = 0 ; i<n ; i++){
            cout << " Enter the " + to_string(i+1) + "th symbol   ";
            cin >> symbols[i] ;
            cout << " Enter the " + to_string(i+1) + "th probability   ";
            cin >> probabilities[i];
        }

        bool flg = performSanityCheck(symbols,probabilities,n);
        //cout << "flg" << flg;
        //printFloatArray(probabilities,n);
        //printCharacterArray(symbols,n);
        if (!flg) break ;
        else{
            cout << " The values provided were not correct . Please make sure that all the entered symbols are unique and all the probabilities sum up to 1 \n";
        } 
    }
    // Construct Huffman Tree 
    struct Node* root  = buildHuffmanTree(symbols, probabilities, n); 
   
    int arr[n], top = 0; 
  
    printHuffManCodes(root, arr, top); 
    cout << " AverageCodeLength: " << AverageCodeLength << endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

In this code, I have tried to build a Huffman tree using minheaps. In the `Heapify` function, when I try to use the `minHeap->array[left]->probability` by storing it's value in a variable named `lprob` it doesn't work; but, when I use it directly in the `if` statement it works. Can somebody tell me why this is happening?

There is no compilation error or something like that when I try to execute it but the execution stops abruptly when I am trying to store it in the variable.

Comment: You should post the code that isn't working, not the code that is. I can imagine various ways to reinstate the commented out code in the Heapify function, but I have no way of telling precisely which code you have when you get the crash.

Comment: @john I have edited it can you have a look at it once . thanks for that will make sure that I post the code to be corrected from next time onwards.

Comment: `int n ; char symbols[n];`. I could be wrong, but I don't think this works as you intended. The logic does not magically go back when seeing `cin >> n ; ` and change the allocations for those two arrays.

Comment: thanks but that works I have checked it after getting the values from the console